# Improving collision detection performance in HTML5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, collision, detection

I'm currently creating a game that involves coins that come up from the bottom of the screen in a random X position. If the hero overlaps/collides with the coins, the user gets a point.

My issue is, when I put my collision detection in a fast interval function, it seems that the collision is not registering at some instances.

I've replicated the game in the jsfiddle below (originally it uses the phone's accelerometer to move the hero but for this example I've quickly made it a left/right key based control) - 
http://jsfiddle.net/wpavxn6k/1/

Snippet of the interval below -

```
//keep checking to see if collision has occured 
window.setInterval(function () {
    if (hitTest(app.hero, app.coinClassUnique) == true) {
        app.coinClassUnique.css('display', 'none');
        app.score++;
        $("h2").html(app.score);
    }
 }, 5);

//measure the width/height and position of the coin div and the hero image to determine if they are overlapping 

function hitTest(a, b) {
    var aPos = a.offset();
    var bPos = b.offset();

    var aLeft = aPos.left;
    var aRight = aPos.left + a.width();
    var aTop = aPos.top;
    var aBottom = aPos.top + a.height();

    var bLeft = bPos.left;
    var bRight = bPos.left + b.width();
    var bTop = bPos.top;
    var bBottom = bPos.top + b.height();

    return !(bLeft > aRight || bRight < aLeft || bTop > aBottom || bBottom < aTop);
}
```

My question is whether you can see an obvious flaw in my code that may be affecting performance, or if there are any tips of how I can improve performance and collision detection in a real-time based game like this.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post the answer for this question incase someone encounters a similar issue. The interval of the game was happening at different times so I rebuilt the game inside a Canvas element with requestFrameAnimation. This way, all the elements reload at once.

I had some issues like images not loading properly etc. at first, which is why I avoided using canvas - but with the help of preloading and rendering the images into separate canvases that are hidden off screen - I was able to tackle these issues.